# Laravel: save model in service provider?

Tags: laravel

I am trying to understand the concepts of the service containers and service providers in Laravel.

At this moment, my application consists of (custom generated) models, views and controllers. So, pretty straightforward.

But now, I am planning to build a cron job which will fetch some data from an external service. This data needs to be stored in my database. I also have a view where users can manually enter the same sort of data. My controller validates the input and saves the model.

However, I don't want to copy the logic of the store function in my controller and I also don't want to call that same function from another controller.

So, I read about service providers. I followed some tutorials and read the docs on laravel.com but I somehow don't get it.

For example, I have two models: "Order" and "OrderEntry". Currently, the only function within these models is a relationship function so I can call $order->entries() and $entry->order().

Like I said I have a OrderController which validates some things and the stores a "Order" with $order->save() in the store method of the OrderController.

What's the best approach for this? I can also write a store function on the model "Order" itself. That way I can also use the same logic on different places in my app.

Answer (score 0):

An ALTERNATE option to service providers and maybe not the end-all-be-all:

I had a requirement for uploading and parsing files, where the user can do it through the UI, but a dev also needs to process files manually. I used a [command](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling) to be able to call it from the controller or from the CLI. Perhaps not as extensible as service providers, but a slightly simpler option. They are particularly easy to call & run from a cron job too.

If you're decided on service providers, they're unfortunately a little fuzzy for me as well. I guess maybe consider the scale of what you want to do, and the reusability of the service provider you're creating. [This post helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53003303/8776302) "get it" a little more, but I have not yet had a scenario where this has been needed. Good luck!