# What, why and how are Laravel service providers PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I started to wonder about what exactly is the purpose of service providers in Laravel, and why they work in the way they do. After searching through some articles,
**the key points of service providers in my understanding are:**

1. Simplifies object creation ([Laravel What is the use of service providers for laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53000712/laravel-what-is-the-use-of-service-providers-for-laravel#answer-53001362))
2. Decoupling your code ([r/laravel: When to use service providers?](https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/4lclxa/when_to_use_service_provider#t1_d3mc42f))
3. Dependency injection
4. Reduces technical debt

So it basically binds an implementation to an interface, and we can use it by

```
$app(MyInterface::class)
```

or something like that, and we can just change the implementation when needed, only in one place, and the rest of our code which depends on it won't break.
But i still can not grasp the concept, why they are the way they are, it seems overcomplicated. I peaked in to the code, it was certainly a ton of work to make **Service Providers & Containers** work, so there must be a good reason.
So to learn further, i tried to make my own, more simple version of it, which achieves the same goals. (i obviously lack a lot of info on this, and most probably missed some other goals)

My question is, why would this implementation would not satisfy the same use cases?

Service.php

```php
namespace MyVendor;
/**
 * Abstract class for creating services
 */
abstract class Service
{
    /**
     * Holds the instance of the provided service
     *
     * @var mixed
     */
    private static mixed $instance = null;

    /**
     * Retrieves the instance of the provided service & creates it on-demand
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function get(): mixed
    {
        if (self::$instance === null) {
            self::$instance = static::instantiate();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    /**
     * A function which contains the service's object creation logic
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    abstract protected static function instantiate(): mixed;
}
```

Example implementation:
For the example, i chose an interface to parse environment variables, as i already had [phpdotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) in my project as a dependency

Services/DotenvParser/DotenvParserInterface.php

```php
namespace MyVendor\Services\DotenvParser;
/**
 * This is the service interface i want to provide
 */
interface DotenvParserInterface
{
    public function parse(string $directory, string $fileName = ".env"): array;
}
```

Now i will have 2 implementations of this class. I will pretend that a lot of my code already depends on `DotenvParserInterface`. An old, hacky one which "depends" on another thing, and the replacement for it which uses phpdotenv

A quick fake dependency:

Services/DotenvParser/Dependency.php

```php
namespace MyVendor\Services\DotenvParser;

class Dependency
{
    private bool $squeeze;
    public string $bar;

    public function __construct(string $foo, bool $squeeze)
    {
        $this->squeeze = $squeeze;
        $this->bar = $foo;
        if($this->squeeze){
            $this->bar .= " JUICE";
        }
    }

}
```

Our old code:
Services/DotenvParser/OldDotenvCode.php

```php
namespace MyVendor\Services\DotenvParser;

use BadMethodCallException;
use InvalidArgumentException;

class OldDotenvCode implements DotenvParserInterface
{
    /**
     * Our fake dependency
     *
     * @var Dependency
     */
    private Dependency $foo;

    private string $dir;

    private string $fileName;
    
    private string $contents;

    private array $result;

    public function __construct(Dependency $myDependency)
    {
        $this->foo = $myDependency;
    }
    
    /**
     * Implementation of DotenvParserInterface
     *
     * @param string $directory
     * @param string $fileName
     * @return array
     */
    public function parse(string $directory, string $fileName = ".env"): array
    {
        try{
            $this->setDir($directory)->setFileName($fileName);
        }catch(BadMethodCallException $e){
            throw new InvalidArgumentException($e->getMessage(), 0, $e);
        }

        $this->getEnvContents();
        $this->contents = $this->getEnvContents();
        $this->result = [];
        foreach(explode("\n", $this->contents) as $line){
            $exploded   = explode("=", $line);
            $key        = $exploded[0];
            $value      = (isset($exploded[1])) ? trim($exploded[1], "\r") : "";
            if($this->foo->bar === "ORANGE JUICE"){
                $value = trim($value, "\"");
            }
            $this->result[$key] = $value;
        }
    
        return $this->result;
    }
    
    #region Old, bad stuff
    public function setDir(string $directory): self{
        if(!\is_dir($directory)){
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Directory $directory is not a valid directory");
        }
        $this->dir = rtrim($directory, "/");
        return $this;
    }

    public function setFileName(string $fileName): self{
        if(empty($this->dir)){
            throw new BadMethodCallException("Must call method setDir() first with a valid directory path");
        }
        
        $fileName = ltrim($fileName, "/");
        if(!\file_exists($this->dir . "/" . $fileName)){
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("File $fileName does not exist in provided directory {$this->dir}");
        }

        $this->fileName = $fileName;
        return $this;
    }

    private function getFilePath(): string{
        if(empty($this->fileName)){
            throw new BadMethodCallException("Must call method setFileName() first");
        }
        return $this->dir . "/" . $this->fileName;
    }

    private function getEnvContents(): string{
        return \file_get_contents($this->getFilePath());
    }

    public function setup(): void
    {
        $this->setDir($directory)->setFileName($fileName);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Now, the phpdotenv version

Services/DotenvParser/phpdotenv.php

```php
namespace MyVendor\Services\DotenvParser;

use Dotenv\Dotenv;
use InvalidArgumentException;

use Dotenv\Dotenv;
use InvalidArgumentException;

class phpdotenv implements DotenvParserInterface
{
    public function parse(string $directory, string $fileName = ".env"): array
    {
        try{
            Dotenv::createMutable($directory, $fileName)->load();
        }catch(\Dotenv\Exception\InvalidPathException $e){
            throw new InvalidArgumentException($e->getMessage(), 0, $e);
        }
        $result = $_ENV;
        $_ENV = [];     //Hehe
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Our service which we made from extending our Service class

Services/DotenvParser/DotenvParserService.php

```php
namespace MyVendor\Services\DotenvParser;

use MyVendor\Service;

class DotenvParserService extends Service
{

    // We can do this to make type hinting for ourselves
    public static function get(): DotenvParserInterface
    {
        return parent::get();
    }

    protected static function instantiate(): DotenvParserInterface
    {
        $year = 2022;

        // Some condition, to return one or another
        if($year < 2022){
            $dep = new \MyVendor\Services\DotenvParser\Dependency("ORANGE", true);
            return new OldDotenvCode($dep);
        }

        return new phpdotenv();
    }
}
```

And now, we can use it like this:

```php
$dotenvparser = \MyVendor\Services\DotenvParser\DotenvParserService::get();
$result = $dotenvparser->parse(__DIR__);
var_dump($result);
// Outputs an array of our environment variables, yey!
```

We can also write tests for our services to see if anything breaks:

```php
namespace MyVendorTest\Services\DotenvParser;

use InvalidArgumentException;
use MyVendor\Services\DotenvParser\DotenvParserInterface;
use MyVendor\Services\DotenvParser\DotenvParserService;

final class DotenvParserServiceTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{

    public function doesInstantiate(): void
    {
        $testParser = DotenvParserService::get();
        $this->assertInstanceOf(DotenvParserInterface::class, $testParser);
    }

    public function testWorksFromValidDirNFile(): void
    {
        // The actual contents of a .env file
        $testArray = [
            "DEV_MODE" => "TRUE",
            "BASE_HREF" => "http://localhost:8080/"
        ];

        $testParser = DotenvParserService::get();
        // phpdotenv loads every parent .env too and i was having none of it for this quick demonstration
        $result = $testParser->parse(__DIR__."/../../../", ".env");

        $this->assertEquals($testArray, $result);
    }

    public function testSetupFromInvalidDir(): void
    {
        $this->expectException(InvalidArgumentException::class);
        $testParser = DotenvParserService::get();
        $testParser->parse("i_am_a_dir_which_does_not_exist");
    }

    public function testSetupFromInvalidFile(): void
    {
        $this->expectException(InvalidArgumentException::class);
        $testParser = DotenvParserService::get();
        $testParser->parse(__DIR__, ".notenv");
    }
}
```

So this ended up quite lenghty, but after having that Service class, you basically only need: An interface, at least one implementation of that interface, and a service class which instantiates an implementation of that interface, and optionally some tests for it. And, you can even do dependency injection with it (??) (circular dependencies would get us stuck in an endless loop), like this:

```php
protected static function instantiate(): FooInterface
{
    //BarService & AcmeService are extending our Service class
    return new FooInterface(BarService::get(), AcmeService::get(), "ORANGE JUICE")
}
```

I am ready to absorb massive amounts of information

1. What other things Laravel's Service providers & containers do than i am aware of?
2. Why and how is it better than a simpler version, like this one?
3. Does my version really achieve at least those 4 key points i mentioned in the start?

Comment: There was one sentence from Jeffrey Way in his videos: "Just put it in a box, make a label on it and forget about it." So that's in short what the service providers are used for.

Comment: @lewis4u Yes, this was the whole reason i started to wonder about it. I'd feel much more confident using them with my version, from `x::get()` i have a return type, i know what i am using and what it can do. Its basically the same, but using static classes instead of a string label